# How do I make a clear warns command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so I am making a warn system I am almost done but there's a problem I have to add a clear warns command, that clears all the warnings for a specific user... But don't know how to. here is my code-

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True, ban_members=True)
async def warn(ctx,user:discord.User,*reason:str):
  if not reason:
    await ctx.send("Please provide a reason")
    return
  reason = ' '.join(reason)
  for current_user in report['users']:
    if current_user['name'] == user.name:
      current_user['reasons'].append(reason)
      await ctx.send("reported sir!")
      await user.send(f"u have been reported for :{reason}")
      break
  else:
    report['users'].append({
      'name':user.name,
      'reasons': [reason,]
    })
  with open('reports.json','w+') as f:
    json.dump(report,f)

@client.command(pass_context = True, aliases=["warns"])
async def warnings(ctx,user:discord.User):
  for current_user in report['users']:
    if user.name == current_user['name']:
      embed = discord.Embed(title="Reports:", description=(f"{user.name} has been reported {len(current_user['reasons'])} times : {','.join(current_user['reasons'])}"))
      await ctx.send(embed= embed)
      break
  else:
    await ctx.send(f"{user.name} has never been reported")
```

Comment: I can see some errors here, but where exactly are you stuck? What is the problem with this code, is it raising an error or performing inefficiently? make that clear in your question

Comment: @Ceres I want to add a clear warns command

Comment: Cool, I did not know there was a discord.py API module available. Gotta look into this myself. btw. Regarding your question: (1) Do you want to add a new @command or alter the ones you posted? (2) Is it important to know the report history or are you okay with just deleting a previous entry in the *.json file?

Comment: @StiggyStardust yea I want to delete a previous entry in the.json file

Comment: I would suggest you see a tutorial or ask friends, for questions related to ideas. Use stack overflow if you can't Implement said idea, or are stuck with an error or don't know what to do with it, refrain from asking to code for you here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me point out the errors in your code.

```py
async def warn(ctx,user:discord.User,*reason:str):
  if not reason:
    await ctx.send("Please provide a reason")
    return
```

The `if` block won't be executed as reason doesn't have a default value, set a default value with `reason:str = None` or the bot will just raise an error if there is no reason.

```
report['users'].append({
      'name':user.name,
      'reasons': [reason,]
    })
```

report is not defined in the code you have posted here, make sure you you read the json file and get the data or you might lose some data.

Finally, the solution

```py
@client.command()
async def clear_warn(ctx, member: discord.Member):
   with open('reports.json', 'r') as f:
        records = json.load(f)
   if member.name in records['users']:
        index = [record['name'] for record in records['users']].index(member.name)
        records.pop(index)
        await ctx.send('removed all warns')
   else:
        await ctx.send('member has no warns')
```

Some things I would point out in your code are

1. Using ids instead of names as names can be changed
2. instead of storing warn data as a list, use id/name as key and a list or reports as the value. It will be easier to access and modify.

Comment: the solution u have given is not working instead of coming up an error its saying "member has no warns"

Comment: Check the json file, and including it in your question would help